# Add new post in existing categories using wp_insert_post

Tags: php, posts, categories, wp-insert-post

I am trying to add a new post using the function `wp_inser_post` in one of my existing categories, I've created a new taxonomy named `categorie` and in that taxonomy i have a few categories, and I am not able to find a solution, the post is being added but no category is selected.

```
  $title =  $_POST['postTitle'];
  $description = $_POST['postContent'];  

  $new_post = array(
    'post_title' => esc_attr(strip_tags($title)),
    'post_content' => esc_attr(strip_tags($description)),
    'post_type' => 'proiecte',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_category' =>  array(17,16),
    'taxonomy'      => 'categorie'
  );

  $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
```

Answer (score 1):

`post_category` is only for Core Categories. Use `tax_input` instead:

```
$new_post = array( 
    'post_title' => esc_attr(strip_tags($title)),
    'post_content' => esc_attr(strip_tags($description)),
    'post_type' => 'proiecte',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'tax_input' => array(
        'categorie' => array(17,16)
    )
);
$post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
```

It may be clearer to other developers, and yourself in the future, if you use something other than `categorie` - perhaps `projecte_category` - just so it's clearer you're using a custom taxonomy and not misspelling Category.

Comment: Thank you! worked like a charm! i will keep in mind your advice in the project to come. Have a nice day !

Answer (score 0):

You can use WordPress's `wp_set_object_terms` to do this. You can call this function after `wp_insert_post` call.

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);

wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'term', 'categorie' );
```

You can pass set multiple terms by passing array of term.
Ceck this for more.https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_object_terms/